# Infinite while loop when calculating binary

Tags: c, function, while-loop

I wrote a function to find binary value of an integer.

```
int binary(int n)
{

 if(n>0)
{
  int x=n%2;
  binary(n/2);
  printf("%d",x);
 }
}
```

This gives the correct output while the below one gives an infinite loop.

```
int binary(int n)
{

 while(n>0)
 {
  int x=n%2;
   binary(n/2);
   printf("%d",x);
 }
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: classic conditional vs loop statement issue. :)

Comment: Because you never update `n`.

Comment: Don;t mix recursion with outer loop, makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call recursive function binary, you send new value which is `2` times smaller than previous. At one point, that value will reach `0`, and `n>0` will be false, so you won't get into loop and you will return from last recursive function. Since you haven't changed value of `n` when you called function again, `n` still has value of 1, and from this point, it won't ever be changed. `1` is always greater than `0`, so you will be stack into infinite loop.